# Expo OTA still works when I add new screens/components?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, ota

as I understand Expo or Codepush OTA is for updating React Native (RN) apps without going through app submission. The reason it's possible is because a RN app has 2 parts:

1. UI: built-in RN components (View, Text...) will be converted to native UI widgets/components (UIView, android.view...). Basically our UI is native.
2. Logic: written in Javascript and cannot be converted to native code. We have to embed a JS Runtime (JavascriptCore, Hermes) to our native app to read and execute JS.

OTA only updates the JS code and cannot update native code.
However, recently I just did an OTA update to add some new features (new screens, new components) and it worked totally fine. I couldn't understand this. Didn't I modify the native code by adding new screens? Does this mean I understand the UI part wrong and our UI is not native but web view?

Hope you guys can help me answer this. Thank you!

Comment: The only thing I understood for sure from Expo's documentation is that you can't get new native modules pushed over-the-air. Assets, components (js code), fonts can be pushed and will be pushed. You need to pay attention to how you push your updates. They suggest one channel per new app release on stores which gives you flexibility to send updates to specific versions of the app so that you don't cause app chrashes for incompatible versions/updates.

I prefer to disable OTA, couldn't find it anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

> Didn't I modify the native code by adding new screens?

No, you didn't modify the native codebase. You modified only the JavaScript codebase unless you add a new library that uses native code.

> Does this mean I understand the UI part wrong and our UI is not native
> but web view?

React Native UI is native and **not** webview. For example, you used components like `View, Text`, etc from `react-native`. It invokes native code and create new instances of Views with different params. While you creating new JavaScript code native code stays the same.
In other words with your on air update you created new invokes of native code. But this native code is same as it was when you submit it in the store.